# Can I revert Apple Mail to its previous behavior with regard to the search box?

Tags: mail.app, search, preferences

In Mac OS 10.14.6 and earlier, when I searched in Mail, it would filter whatever folder I was viewing, but then if I clicked on a different folder I would be shown the full contents of that folder.

Now that I've updated to Mac OS 12.4, this behavior has changed.  Now I have to explicitly close the search box (clear the search), otherwise all folders I click to will ALL be filtered according to the search I put in.

I recognize that some might regard this as a feature, especially if they need to click through multiple folders before they find what they're searching for, but I find it annoying.

Is there a way to restore the previous behavior?  Failing that, is there at least a keyboard shortcut or menu item (for which I could then add a keyboard shortcut) to clear the current search, rather than being absolutely required to click on the little tiny "X"?

Comment: As an aside, the interface elements are way, way smaller on the new Mail compared to the old.  I don't know if there's a way to fix that.

Comment: ⌥ + ⌘ + F (activating cursor in Mail searchbox and selecting all of its content if applicable) and then ⌫ to delete